# Snaps not found after reboot

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, snap

I've installed apps through Snap (like Slack and Spotify) and they worked great right after install. Unfortunately, I'm not able to find them after restarting (reboot) my PC. A look at `snap list` shows the list of the apps I installed earlier.

```
Name             Version                  Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
code-insiders    ec0d1978                 419   latest/stable  vscode✓     classic
core             16-2.44.1                8935  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
core18           20200311                 1705  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
slack            4.4.2                    23    latest/stable  slack✓      classic
snapd            2.44.1                   6953  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
spotify          1.1.26.501.gbe11e53b-15  41    latest/stable  spotify✓    -
```

I also find the snaps folders under `~/home/snap`.

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64, and KDE.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and execute `snap run slack` or `snap run spotify`?

Comment: Hi @dk-bose. Yes, running `snap run slack` does start Slack. How can I make it launchable from the Application Launcher like it was before the restart?